# How can I repair this uneven cabinet finish?

Tags: cabinets

How can I restore the look of these cabinets?

The previous home owners appear to have applied some kind of product on top of a few of the kitchen cabinets which is not easily removed. Is there a way to bring back something close to the original look without sanding them down and completely refinishing? The other cabinets in the room look fine, so matching that finish is important because I don't want to have to refinish all the cabinets to make them match.

Howard Feed-N-Wax made the other cabinets look better, but did nothing for this unevenness. Also, I couldn't lighten up the dark parts with alcohol- or acetone-based solutions.

[image]

Comment: Not really. That kind of color shift isn't easily repairable.

Comment: "Easy solutions" consist of the all too common - "Hardwood cabinets? - Let's slap a coat of paint on those so they look like cheap MDF cabinets!" If you want wood, expect to work.

Comment: Usually if matching is important and cleaning/waxing does not help, then starting at the beginning(sanding/stripping) or covering it(paint) completely are the only good choices for matching.  Paint should be very low on the list if that is real wood.

Comment: You're fortunate that those are a very simple design. Start with stripping, then some sanding as necessary. The flat surfaces make sanding much easier, and the lack of intricate detail makes stripping easier.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you start with one of the drawer fronts, and sand or strip it as is your preference, (because a magic method that does not require that requires magic we don't seem to have in this universe, unless it's the "magic" of "pay someone else to do that for you") and then sort out a process to match (to the extent you care to) the cabinets you don't want to touch, then repeat one drawer front or door at a time.

Those parts are easily removed from the kitchen to a better location for making a mess, and you *may* not need to do the cabinet frames once you have them done.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mess that was created by taking multiple shortcuts. Each shortcut creates more work to fix. If you don’t want to strip all the finish off on the damaged areas, proper prep and paint will be the easiest choice for a homeowner. You could hire an artist to try to blend the miscellaneous different finishes.

Comment: This answer would be useful if you described what this "proper prep" was. Otherwise, it's really just a comment...